# exporting the holotoolkit example to windows store (UWP) gives error

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

When i try to run the holotoolkit example and export to windows store (UWP) i get the following error.

Assets\HoloToolkit\SpatialMapping\Scripts\RemoteMapping\RemoteMeshSource.cs(142,45): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IAsyncAction' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\HoloToolkit\SpatialMapping\Scripts\RemoteMapping\RemoteMeshSource.cs(142,69): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AsyncStatus' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\HoloToolkit\SpatialMapping\Scripts\RemoteMapping\RemoteMeshSource.cs(184,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IAsyncOperation<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\HoloToolkit\SpatialMapping\Scripts\RemoteMapping\RemoteMeshSource.cs(184,70): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AsyncStatus' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\HoloToolkit\SpatialMapping\Scripts\RemoteMapping\RemoteMeshSource.cs(33,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StreamSocket' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and in

```
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_METRO
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Foundation;

#endif
```

if I comment the #if and #endif I get the following error
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: This happened to me as well as soon as I did update Visual Studio 2017. I did not change anything in the project itself. I have then updated Windows 10 to the latest Creators Update. I also changed Unity's External Script Editor to Visual Studio 2017 since I was using 2015 before the 2017 update. Everything restarted to work as usual after all that.